# Do form validation with jquery ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, forms, codeigniter, validation

How can i do form validation in codeigniter if i don't want to refresh the page?
Basically i do this:

```
    $config = array(
            array(
                    'field' => 'c_name',
                    'label' => 'Name',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required'
            ),
            array(
                    'field' => 'c_job',
                    'label' => 'Job',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                    )
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
    if($this->form_validation->run() == true)
            {
                $this->load->model('model');
                //.....
            }
    else{
            $this->load->view('view');
        }
```

But if i send data with ajax and the page doesn't refresh, How can i do form validation?

Edit:

Thanks @ Amra Kojon. That's good and works but the new problem is this:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                echo validation_errors();
                } 
                else {
                        //echo 'hi';


                        $value = $this->input->post('value');

                        $values = array(
                                'c_name' => $value['c_name'],
                                'c_job'=> $value['c_job'],
                                'c_address'=> $value['c_address'],
                                'c_phone'=> $value['c_phone'],
                                'c_mail'=> $value['c_mail'],
                                'c_state'=> $value['c_state'],
                                'c_intrest'=> $value['c_intrest'],
                                'c_added_info'=> $value['c_added_info']
                        );


                        $add = $this->customers_model->add_customer($values);
                        echo $add;
                }
```

If i just say echo "something" in the else part, It works and if the validation were OK, It echo hi but if i write theme in database (Which the value array has data and in not ajax way, it insert date), It doesn't work and the else part isn't working!!!

Comment: if you using ajax use jquery validation.

Comment: Simple Use Jquery Validation in browser side and and use server side validation in codeigniter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you gave your JS- jquery Ajax code it would more efficient to understand your problem.. Don't worry! Try my following instruction...

1. Get get form value and pass to form as

   $(document).ready(function(){
        var dataString = $("#FormId").serialize();
        var url="ControllerName/MethodName"
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:""+url,
            data:dataString,
            success:function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
            });     
      })

Controller :

2. Load library form_validation in construct as ...

   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->load->helper('form');
3. Now write your controller as ...

   ```
   function MethodName {
   $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','First Name', 'required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','Last Name', 'required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email Address','required|valid_email|is_unique[sec_users.email]');
   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
       echo validation_errors();
   } 
   else {
     // To who are you wanting with input value such to insert as 
     $data['frist_name']=$this->input->post('fname');
     $data['last_name']=$this->input->post('lname');
     $data['user_name']=$this->input->post('email');
     // Then pass $data  to Modal to insert bla bla!!
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Thanks @ Amra Kojon :) I updated the question. See that please.

Comment: @user1767712 would you please give your html and model code please which will help me to give exact solution. Thank you!

Comment: @meph, I am also getting the same issue, May I know how you display the error message on the view page? because currently, the error message is displaying on response.

Answer (score 9):

I know your question is a year old but you can use this for the latest bootstrap with codeigniter

```
<?php

class Yourcontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('template/register');
    }

    public function validate() {

        $json = array();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password', 'required|matches[password]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('code', 'Login Code', 'required|numeric|min_length[4]||max_length[8]');

        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'You missed the input {field}!');

        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            $json = array(
                'username' => form_error('username', '<p class="mt-3 text-danger">', '</p>'),
                'email' => form_error('email', '<p class="mt-3 text-danger">', '</p>'),
                'password' => form_error('password', '<p class="mt-3 text-danger">', '</p>'),
                'confirm_password' => form_error('confirm_password', '<p class="mt-3 text-danger">', '</p>'),
                'code' => form_error('code', '<p class="mt-3 text-danger">', '</p>')
            );
        }

        $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($json));

    }
}
```

Ajax Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#error').html(" ");

    $('#form-submit-button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('yourcontroller/validate');?>", 
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('#input-' + key).addClass('is-invalid');

                    $('#input-' + key).parents('.form-group').find('#error').html(value);
                });
            }
        });
    });

    $('#form input').on('keyup', function () { 
        $(this).removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
        $(this).parents('.form-group').find('#error').html(" ");
    });
});
</script>
```

Full View Code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 ml-auto mr-auto m-auto">
            <div class="card mt-5">
                <h5 class="card-header"></h5>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <?php echo form_open('agent/register', array('id' => 'form', 'role' => 'form'));?>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php echo form_input('username', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Agent Username', 'id' => 'input-username'));?>
                        <div id="error"></div>
                    </div>

                    <hr/>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php echo form_input('email', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Agent Email', 'id' => 'input-email'));?>
                        <div id="error"></div>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php echo form_password('password', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Password', 'id' => 'input-password'));?>
                        <div id="error"></div>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php echo form_password('confirm_password', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Confirm Password', 'id' => 'input-confirm_password'));?>
                        <div id="error"></div>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr/>

                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-dark" id="form-submit-button">Register Agent</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php echo form_close();?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#error').html(" ");

    $('#form-submit-button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('yourcontroller/validate');?>", 
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $('#input-' + key).addClass('is-invalid');

                    $('#input-' + key).parents('.form-group').find('#error').html(value);
                });
            }
        });
    });

    $('#agent-register-form input').on('keyup', function () { 
        $(this).removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
        $(this).parents('.form-group').find('#error').html(" ");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this is more clearer and complete than the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware about passing data with ajax, then the work flow is as follows.

> 1) Send form data through ajax to your controller.
>
> 2) Do form validation as of now.
>
> 3) If success then "echo" value 1
>
> 4) If failure, echo value 0

So that using the value in echo, you can determine whether the validation fails or not. I can give you an example if you need

**Sample ajax code**

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 1){
                $('#form')[0].reset();
                alret('success');
            }
            else if(data == 0){
                alret('failed');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create MY_Form_validation in libraries folder

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
private $json = array();
private $opts = array();

function get_json($extra_array = array(),$error_array=array())
    {
        if(count($extra_array)) {
            foreach($extra_array as $addition_key=>$addition_value) {
                $this->json[$addition_key] = $addition_value;
            }
        }
        $this->json['options'] = $this->opts;
        if(!empty($error_array)){
            foreach($error_array AS $key => $row)
                $error[] = array('field' => $key, 'error' => $row);
        }
        foreach($this->_error_array AS $key => $row)
            $error[] = array('field' => $key, 'error' => $row);


        if(isset($error)) {
            $this->json['status'] = 'error';
            $this->json['errorfields'] = $error;
        } else {
            $this->json['status'] = 'success';      
        }   
        return json_encode($this->json);
    }
}

Call this function in controller if validation failed:
echo $this->form_validation->get_json();

You get the response with form fieldname and errormessage

Example:
{"options":[],"status":"error","errorfields":[{"field":"email","error":"The Mobile Number\/Email\/Username field is required."},{"field":"password","error":"The Password field is required."}]}
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this is my working (Codeigniter 3.0) basic example to achieve what you want do

include filename.js in your view

```
document.getElementById("yourForm").reset();

$(document).ready( function() {
var yourForm = $('#yourForm');
  yourForm.submit( function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
      type: 'POST',
      url: yourForm.attr( 'action' ),
      data: yourForm.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
            if (data.code == '200') {
            $('#message').html(data.message);    
            document.getElementById("yourForm").reset();
            }
      },
      error: function(data) {
         var response = data.responseText;
         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            if (obj.code == '500') {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < obj.field.length; i++) {
                  name = obj.field[i];
                  $('.label-'+name).addClass('label-error');
              errors = JSON.stringify(obj.validation);
              validate = jQuery.parseJSON(errors);
              $('.helper-'+name).html(validate[name]);
                }
            }
      }
    } );
  } );
} );
```

view HTML form example
In this example in am using className you can use id as well change filename.js file accordingly

```
<form id="yourForm" action="base_url/controller/function_name" action="POST">
// Important text after className "label-" & "helper-" must be input name
<label class="label-firstName">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" />
<span class="helper-firstName"></span>
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
```

controller PHP code

```
public function function_name()
{
    if(!empty($_POST)) {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstName','First Name','required|max_length[16]');


        if($this->form_validation->run())     
        {
            $params = array(
                'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'),
                );
            // Model returning $data['newRecord'] with $params and insertId 
            $data['newRecord'] = $this->Record_model->newRecord($params);

            $reply = array();
            $reply['code'] = 200;
            $reply['record'] = array(
                        'insertId' => $data['newRecord']['insertId'],
                        'firstName' => $data['newRecord']['firstName']
                        );
            $reply['message'] = 'Hello, ' .$data['newRecord']['firstName']. ' - We have received your message. ' .$data['newRecord']['insertId']. ' is your reference ID, for this communication.';            
            header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
            print json_encode($reply);
        }
        else {
           $validation = $this->form_validation->error_array();
           $field = array();
                    foreach($validation as $key => $value) {
                        array_push($field,$key);
                    }
            $reply = array(
                'code' => 500,
                'field' => $field,
                'validation' => $validation,
                'message' => 'Submission failed due to validation error.'
                );
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Problem', true, 500);
            header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
            print json_encode($reply);
        }
    }
    else {
            $reply = array();
            $reply['code'] = 403;
            $reply['message'] = 'No Direct Access Allowed.';
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 403 Forbidden', true, 403);
            header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
            print json_encode($reply);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If using ajax,...you can't use form_validation library 
So you can validate on client side using jquery ...and on server side should use if statement to check submitted data

Comment: Nope, that's not true. You can use form_validation library using or not using ajax.