# how to validate form input field if form value inserted through jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

view:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#insert" ).click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            var name= $("#name").val();
            var email= $("#email").val();
            var phone= $("#phone").val();
            var message= $("#message").val();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"post",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/'); ?>test/register",
                    data:{"name": name, "email":email, "phone":phone, "message":message},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#msd').text('Your Enquiry Has Been Sent. We Will Inform You Soon.');
                        $('#name,#email,#message,#phone').val('');
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="bg-image">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id" required>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" required>

                            <textarea class="form-control1" name="message" id="message"  placeholder="Enter Your Message" required></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h4>Features</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <h4>Fotter</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
public function register()
{
    $register  = $this->Fetch_data->contact();
    if(!empty($register_user))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

models:

```
public function contact()
  {
     $data = array(
        'name'  => $this->input->post('name'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
        's_date' => date('Y-m-d')
     );
     $this->db->insert('contact', $data);
  }
```

In this code I have create a form inside the modal where I am inserting form value into database table name contact. Here, form value are inserting successfully but the validation are not working properly. If input field empty they show nothing like field is mandatory. So, How can we give validation to all field please help me ?

Thank You

Comment: use backend validation using PHP

Comment: You should have validation at front-end as well as the back-end

Comment: I have already given required to all input field but they are also not working why?

Comment: You can validate using `jQuery` at the client side, and `PHP` server side __(just in case, a user disables javascript in his/her browser)__

Comment: @omkara, if you're not sending `files`, why put the form attribute `enctype` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185883/do-form-validation-with-jquery-ajax-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

Replace `<script>` To

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#insert").click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            var name= $("#name").val();
            var email= $("#email").val();
            var phone= $("#phone").val();
            var message= $("#message").val();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"post",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/'); ?>test/register",
                    dataType:'JSON',
                    data:{"name": name, "email":email, "phone":phone, "message":message},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#msd').text(data.message);
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function register()
   {
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $post = $this->input->post();

      if (!empty($post)) {

//validate form input
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'required');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'required');

         if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $register = $this->Fetch_data->contact($post);
            if (!empty($register)) {

               echo json_encode(array("status" => false, "message" => "Inserted Successfully"));
               exit(0);
            } else {
               echo json_encode(array("status" => false, "message" => "Unable to insert Try later"));
               exit(0);
            }
         } else {
            echo json_encode(array("status" => false, "message" => validation_errors()));
            exit(0);
         }
      } else {
         echo json_encode(array("status" => false, "message" => "Invalid Request"));
         exit(0);
      }
   }
```

Model

```
public function contact($post)
   {
      $data = array(
                               'name' => $post['name'],
                               'email' => $post['email'],
                               'phone' => $post['phone'],
                               'message' => $post['message'],
                               's_date' => date('Y-m-d', time())
      );
      $this->db->insert('contact', $data);
      return $this->db->insert_id();
   }
```

If You got any error then let me know

Note

> Note : Enable Form_validation library